# Origin of the usage of "Man" as a word of exclamation

Tags: etymology

What is the origin of the usage of the word "Man" as a word of exclamation?

> *Man* this curry is delicious!
>
> *Man* my feet hurt!

Comment: "Boy" also seems to work in those contexts. Are *man* and *boy* related?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It started as a generic vocative expression, like calling somebody "buddy" today -- the word meant "person", the sense of "adult male" came later.  According to the OED, it started to switch over to being a more general interjection about 1823.

Comment: Etymonline [adds](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=man), "As an interjection of surprise or emphasis, first recorded c.1400, but especially popular from early 20c.".